# .animate({ width: 'toggle' }) without messing up the content

Tags: jquery

So I'm having a problem with my left-sliding div. Currently I'm using `$('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' });` to show it, but while it is sliding it looks like the the content inside of it gets their float ignored. They are fixed after the div stops sliding, but it's a weird effect while it slides. The codes I'm using:

```
// Search bar dropdown script

    function searchBar() {
        $('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        $('#searchBoxButton').fadeToggle('fast');
    }

    function searchBarClose() {
        $('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
        $('#searchBoxButton').fadeToggle('fast');
    }
```

---

```
<div id="searchBoxButton" onclick="searchBar()"></div>
<div id="searchBox">
    <form>
        <div id="magnifier"></div>
        <input id="searchBoxInput" placeholder="Search me" type="text"/>
        <div class="closeButton" onclick="searchBarClose()"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

```
    #searchBoxButton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -5px auto 0 auto;
}

#searchBox {
    display: none;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin: -5px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #202020;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 3px 0;
    border: 1px solid #151515;
}

#searchBox input[type="text"] {
    width: 150px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px 2px;
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS" sans-serif;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    float:left;
}

#searchBox input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 1px solid #797979;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px #797979;
    background-color: #444444;
}

#searchBoxInput::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #7d7d7d;
}
#searchBoxInput:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #7d7d7d;
}
#searchBoxInput::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #7d7d7d;
}
#searchBoxInput:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #7d7d7d;
}

#magnifier {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/13x13") no-repeat;
    width: 13px; height: 13px;
    float: left;
    margin: 7px 6px;
}

.closeButton {
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/15x15") center no-repeat;
    width: 15px; height: 15px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#searchBox .closeButton {
    margin: 7px 4px;
    float: left;
}

.closeButton:hover {
    background-color: #373737;
    -webkit-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.closeButton:active {
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

I know a workaround for this problem would be using absolute positions on `#magnifier`, `#searchBoxInput` and `.closeButton`, but that wouldn't be good for me. Is there any other way to do this?

Fiddle: http://tinker.io/ef4f7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is behaving so because of the width. It doesn't have enough width to show the items floating on the same line. There is no enough width to show them. Instead you can toggle right position.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28pZ3/)

```
 function searchBar() {
        $('#searchBox').animate({ right: 'toggle' });
        $('#searchBoxButton').fadeToggle('fast');
    }

    function searchBarClose() {
        $('#searchBox').animate({ right: 'toggle' });
        $('#searchBoxButton').fadeToggle('fast');
    }
```

With slide Effect

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LRVPe/)

```
function searchBar() {
      $('#searchBox').show('slide', {
          direction: 'right'
      }, 2000);
      $('#searchBoxButton').fadeToggle('slow');
  }

  function searchBarClose() {
      $('#searchBox').hide('slide', {
          direction: 'right'
      }, 2000, function () {
          $('#searchBoxButton').fadeToggle('slow');
      });

  }
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it slide like the old one was using? This way it seems to just appear without any effect. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: @Gus see my answer below with working jsfiddle. I think its what you want.

Comment: Yes you can have slide effect with jquery ui effects.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jsfiddle functioning more like you want using width instead of right. Note I changed some of your CSS and excluded the search button itself as I didn't have access to that image. But in short here is the main fix:

```
function searchBar() {
        $('input').fadeIn('fast', function () {
          $('#searchBox').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
      });

}
```

See you need that input box width so that you don't have the sizing issue. the above should work and here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chazelton/2n84g/1/)

NOTE: there is an extra anchor there just to demo again as I didn't have access to your magnifier button but you should get the idea. Let me know if its not functioning as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used placeholder images on the fiddle but forgot to update it on the code, already edited the post. So the basic idea would be hiding the input, magnifier and closeButton and showing them up when the searchBar() function is called? I'm having some trouble to adapt it but I think I got the basic idea.

Comment: @Gus if correct please mark as correct. if you need further assistance update the fiddle with correct references and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: http://tinker.io/ef4f7 this one have placeholder images, should work just fine. the searchBoxButton is supposed to be a black tile.

Comment: Nevermind, PSL's answer solved my problem. I really apreciate your time to help me, though. Thanks!