# Stop lines from wrapping when using jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have this fiddle set up: https://jsfiddle.net/xwb9594m/

As you can see when the slide menu gets toggled off, the content wraps as the menu shrinks. I'm trying to just get it to slide away off the side of the screen cleanly.

This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var menuBtn = $('.video-search-button'),
             menu = $('.video-search-menu'),
            close = $('.video-search-menu .close');

      menuBtn.click(function(){
          menu.animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });

      close.click(function(){
         menu.animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });

});
```

and my SCSS:

```
.video-search-menu {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: auto;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #24637e;
background: rgba(36, 99, 126, 0.9);
color: #fff;
z-index: 101;

&-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 180px 50px 0 50px;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:before, &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 50%;
        height: 2px;
        background: #ffffff;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

    &:after {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.animate({ width: 'toggle' }) without messing up the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641989/animate-width-toggle-without-messing-up-the-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I updated your** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/xwb9594m/2/)
Or copy the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          var menuBtn = $('.video-search-button'),
                 menu = $('.video-search-menu'),
                close = $('.video-search-menu .close');

                    var right = (1 - menu.width()) - 1;
                menu.css('right', right);

          menuBtn.click(function(){
              menu.animate({right: 0}).show();
          });

          close.click(function(){
             menu.animate({right: right});
          });

});
```

**Update:** Close menu on clicking again on the button

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/xwb9594m/3/)

Or copy the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

          var menuBtn = $('.video-search-button'),
                 menu = $('.video-search-menu'),
                close = $('.video-search-menu .close');

                    var right = (1 - menu.width()) - 1;
                menu.css('right', right);

          menuBtn.click(function(){
              if(menu.is(':visible')) {
                close.trigger('click');
              }
              else {
                menu.animate({right: 0}).show();
              }
          });

          close.click(function(){
             menu.animate({right: right}, function() {
                menu.hide();
             });
          });

});
```

**Update 2:**
You can also save some lines of code for your close-"icon":

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/xwb9594m/4/)

Comment: That's great, but is there a way that clicking the button again will also close the menu if it is already open?

Answer (score 3):

Add a CSS rule

```
p{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```