# Slide Div right to left with a bump effect

Tags: jquery

Right now when using `slideToggle` my div will **expand** from top to bottom.
If I use `toggle`, it will **expand** from top-right to bottom-left.

What I would like to do is have my div **slide** from right to left when it is toggled and be able to properly apply an effect and a duration to it.

I've done my researches and consulted the manuals but I read that the `toggle` function is deprecated since 1.7 (yet it still work when I use it with JQuery 3.1.1 ?) and most exemples are set using toggle instead of `slideToggle`. I think I'm getting very confused...

- What is the correct way to make a slideToggle from right to
  left, with an effect and a duration ?
- Why is `toggle` still working when I read it got deprecated then
  removed in 1.8 ?

Right now I'm just using the cdn of the minified version of JQuery 3.1.1, do I need something else ?
My div's position is set to `absolute` and `right: 0`.

```
$("#nav").click(function(event){
    $("#menu").slideToggle(600);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.animate(width:'toggle')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16642239/2813224). It is the this version of `toggle()` that's deprecated on 1.8 and removed on 1.9:

> Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate click

See https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ for details.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$("#nav").click(function(event) {
  $('#menu').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 250);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='nav'>TOGGLE</button>
<aside id='menu'>
  <ol>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
  </ol>
</aside>
```